# Convert @Build to Grails 3

Tags: grails, spock, grails-3.0

I am converting a grails 3 app that has a line like this in the unit tests...

```
import grails.buildtestdata.mixin.Build
....
@Build([Item, Parent])
```

Is there an equivalent in say Spock 1.0_GRAILS_2.4 or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Build` is from the build-test-data plugin, which is available for [Grails 2](http://grails.org/plugin/build-test-data) and [Grails 3+](https://grails.org/plugins.html#plugin/build-test-data)

Comment: The grails3+ one looks like a blank screen to me.

Comment: I'm seeing that now also, but the source repo has documentation on usage and installation: https://github.com/longwa/build-test-data

Comment: Also as a side note make sure all build data related items are in integration-tests instead of test. Finally confirmation my definition was correct :-)